# GROUP BY one field in SQL and combine a specific field of all grouped rows to one column

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I need to group SQL results by a specific field, while at the same time I need all values of a specific column of the grouped rows to be returned in one field (like so values1,value2,value3 etc)

example data:

```
NAME id 
john 1
john 2
john 3
maria 4
maria 5
```

result I need:

```
john 1,2,3
maria 4,5
```

Is this possible and how?

Comment: In MySQL you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: thank you so much. I knew it had to be simple, I just didn't know how to google this

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and here is the simple example of GROUP_CONCAT, You may get your desired output after run this/ execute this. The example is with a delimiter ', ' as well, so you can quick understand the things.

The GROUP_CONCAT function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values

```
SELECT name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY name;
```

This may help you.